# make records fetched from database as responsive

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap framework.
i have code like this

```html
<?php
$id=$_GET["pid"];
$query="Select * FROM product WHERE pid='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($query) or trigger_error(mysql_error());
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$image=$row['image'];  --->image path
$head=$row['head'];
?>

<div class="col-md-12">
<ul class="cgrid">
  <li>
    <a href=<?php echo "\" page.php?pid=$id \"" ;?>><?php echo $image;?>   
    <h4><?php echo $head ;?></h4>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>

<?php
}
?>
```

`.cgrid li {width: -webkit-calc(100% / 3);}`
I have included responsive CDN as well.
Let's say i have 6 records in my database that fetches as 3 records per row.
What i want is:I want the records to be responsive ie.,i don't want it to stretch ,i want it to align it to 2 or 1 for a row as the screen size decreases. how can i achieve this ?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Is it CSS issue or PHP issue?

Comment: @ShaunakShukla -thank you very much for your reply.I solved it.It's a CSS issue.I separated <ul> from the loop and it worked. :)